# Create a named range in excel sheet using oledb and C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, named, range

I am attempting to create a named range in an excel sheet using c# and oledb.  I do not want to use the COM object interops for this.  I have not been able to find any online example of performing this task, although reading from a named range is prevalent.

The background is that I will have external data (Xml fragments from an Sql Database table) that need to be used in dropdown lists in various sheets in this Excel workbook, the values of which I will not know until the Excel file is selected and opened by the program.  Part of the preprocessing of the workkbook is to create and load these dropdown lists. The creation will be to create named ranges in a hidden sheet, and then create the dropdown lists on the other sheets, referencing the named ranges (I am not sure I can do this without resorting to the COM interop, but try I must).